# webkit-scrollbar não funciona na versão desktop

Tags: html, css

Bom dia pessoal.
Estou fazendo uma aplicação web com html5 e css3, preciso de uma sessão de rolagem horizontal.
Na versão mobile está funcionando, porem na versão desktop não funciona o scroll.

segue abaixo o código em html e css:

HTML

```html
<section class="projetos-teste">
            <div class="projetos-teste__item projetos-teste1">
                  
            </div>
            <div class="projetos-teste__item projetos-teste2">
                
            </div>
            <div class="projetos-teste__item projetos-teste3">
                
            </div>
            
        </section>
```

CSS:

```css
.projetos-teste {
    max-height: 1600px;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.projetos-teste::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0;
}

.projetos-teste__item {
    min-width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    line-height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.projetos-teste1 {
    background-image: url('../img/projetos/heavy-metal-machine/carousel-1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.projetos-teste2 {
    background-image: url('../img/projetos/heavy-metal-machine/carousel-2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.projetos-teste3 {
    background-image: url('../img/projetos/heavy-metal-machine/carousel-3.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -3):

Aqui funcionou o scroll com esse código que passou.

Tenta usar essa classe assim, removendo o "display: flex":

```
.projetos-teste {
    max-height: 1600px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Se não, tenta deixar uma altura fixa pra esse classe.

Comment: bom dia Arthur, obrigado pelo retorno.
Ele funciona na versão mobile.
quando abre o devTools ele funciona, o cursor muda para touch ai ele faz o scroll.
mas no desktop ele não faz o scroll na horizontal.
se eu tirar o display flex.. ele  funciona o scroll só que na vertical.

Comment: Ah sim, interpretei errado a pergunta, mas ainda assim é estranho o comportamento.
Refiz e testei remover o "overflow-x", dai o scroll horizontal seguiu aparecendo tanto no mobile quanto no web; Não tenho ideia do porque.

https://jsfiddle.net/6rgmkqeh

Comment: Então eu achei estranho também.
eu tentei remover o "overflow-x", mas continua sem funcionar.
se eu remover o 
" .projetos-teste::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0;
}" funciona!
Mas a barra de scroll fica visível e eu preciso que ela fique oculta.